# The given data was invalid. updating function with file uplaod in laravel 8 vue 2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

i'm trying to make an update function with file upload

here is what i have tried so far

```
<b-form @submit.prevent="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
.
.
      <b-form-file
        v-model="invoice.file"
        placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
        drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
        v-on:change="onChange"
      />
      <b-button
      v-ripple.400="'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)'"
      type="submit"
      variant="primary"
      class="mr-1">
      Submit
    </b-button>
</b-form>
```

data in script:

```
data() {
return {
  invoice: {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    file: "",
    _method: "patch"
  }
};
},
```

Methods in script:

```
methods: {
onChange(e) {
  this.file = e.target.files[0];
},
async update() {
  await this.axios
    .post(`/api/auth/outstanding-payment/${this.$route.params.id}`, this.invoice)
    .then((response) => {
      this.$router.push({ name: "apps-invoice-list" });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, 
},
```

controller (update function):

```
public function update(Request $request, OutstandingPayment $outstandingPayment)
{

    $upload = OutstandingPayment::find($outstandingPayment);

    $this->validate($request,[
           'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
           .
           .
           .
           .
    ]);

    if($request->file()) {


            $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file_path = $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'), $file_name);
            $upload->payment_voucher_supporting_doc = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $upload->path = '/storage/' . $file_path;
            $upload->save();


  $upload->update($request->all());

  return ['message' => 'Success'];
}
```

and after submitting the form i'm getting this response (422):

```
The given data was invalid.
```

[image]

i am uploading a file with pdf extension

and the storing function is working fine as showing below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
           'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048',
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
        ]);

        $fileUpload = new OutstandingPayment([
            .
            .
            .
            .
        ]);

        if($request->file()) {


            $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file_path = $request->file('file')->move(public_path('uploads/outstandingPayment'), $file_name);
            $fileUpload->payment_voucher_supporting_doc = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileUpload->path = '/storage/' . $file_path;
            $fileUpload->save();

            return response()->json(['success'=>'File uploaded successfully.']);
        }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

is it from controller side or the script side?

Comment: Firstly above the validation add dd($request->file). If you see the file then it is the controller side, if it return "" or null then its the script side. Cheers!

Comment: Check your requet's headers on the browser, see if you are truly sending a file and if it multipart or not

Answer (score 0):

first you should use sperate requests for both storing and updating.

```
Route::post('...', '...') // for store (called by this.axios.post() methods)
Route::put('...', '...') // for updating (called by this.axios.put() methods)
```

Second, make sure you will have to upload file not string, as postman shows you,
you will need to upload file by using FORMDATA as below:

```
 let config = {};
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', this.file);
 formData.append('name', this.name); // other params as you want to send along
 ...
 
   this.axios.put(`/api/auth/outstanding-payment/${this.$route.params.id}`, formData, config)
   .then(function (response) {
     currentObj.success = response.data.success;
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     currentObj.output = error;
   });
```

for reference you can see exmaple ["Vue/laravel file upload example"](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-vue-js-file-upload-exampleexample.html).